# installing NVIDIA driver 367 blackens the graphic mode

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I have UBUNTU 14.04 LTS installed on my machine and I wanted to install the nvidia driver 367.35 (have chosen this driver according to the specific nvidia card I have (GeforceGT 630M) )
I have followed the same instructions mentioned on many websites:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
$ sudo reboot
```

But when I reboot, my machine turns black and I can't access the graphical mode. I tried blacklisting `"nouveau"` and several other solutions but it turns out always the same.

Anyone could help me please ?